# Q:Retrieve Data From Sql DB into TextFields?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

Im trying to retrieve data (Integer & String) from my sql Table to textfields,
What i did , is creating a class "TextFieldsData" to hold the data nice and clean , as i set up a method on "DataAccessObject" the class that i did for handling Database connection , and last i create a method on my controller class to display the data on textfields.
i got no compile or runtime error when i run the program but i don't see any changes on my textfields !
i don't know what i missed up .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5hjR.png)

```js
class:DataAccessObject
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

    public ObservableList <TextFieldsData> getTextFieldData (String query){
    ObservableList<TextFieldsData> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try {
                connect = database.getConnection();
                pstmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()) {
                    
                list.add(new TextFieldsData(rs.getString("ADSN_ID"),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11)));
                    }
  }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return list;
    }; 
}
```

```css
class:LayoutController
//Button
bt_db_edit.setOnAction(e->
{editFormul();
});

private void editFormul(){
    TextFieldsData items = new TextFieldsData("","","","","","","","","","","") ;
    queryy = "SELECT * FROM a4_textfields WHERE a4_textfields.ADSN_ID="+ID+"";
    doa.getTextFieldData(queryy);
    g2_txtf_1.setText(items.getG2_txtf_1());
    g2_txtf_2.setText(items.getG2_txtf_2());
    g2_txtf_3.setText(items.getG2_txtf_3());
    g2_txtf_4.setText(items.getG2_txtf_4()); 
    txtf_autre.setText(items.getTxtf_autre());
    g6_txf1.setText(items.getG6_txf1());
    txtf_hours.setText(items.getTxtf_hours());
    txtf_minutes.setText(items.getTxtf_minutes());
    g6_txf2.setText(items.getG6_txf2());
    g6_txf3.setText(items.getG2_txtf_3());
    txtf_adsn.setText(items.getADSN());  
    
    };
    
    //ID i get this from a row table it work normally
```

```html
Class:TextFieldsData
public class TextFieldsData {

private  String ADSN ;  
private  String txtf_hours ;
private  String txtf_minutes; 
private  String g2_txtf_1 ;
private  String g2_txtf_2 ;
private  String g2_txtf_3 ;
private  String g2_txtf_4 ;
private  String txtf_autre ;
private  String g6_txf1 ;
private  String g6_txf2 ;
private  String g6_txf3;


public TextFieldsData(String pADSN,String ptxtf_hours, 
                        String ptxtf_minutes ,String pg2_txtf_1 ,String pg2_txtf_2 ,String pg2_txtf_3 ,
                        String pg2_txtf_4 ,String ptxtf_autre , String pg6_txf1 ,String pg6_txf2 ,String pg6_txf3)
{
this.ADSN=new String (pADSN);
this.txtf_hours =new String (ptxtf_hours);
this.txtf_minutes =new String (ptxtf_minutes);
this.g2_txtf_1 =new String (pg2_txtf_1);
this.g2_txtf_2 =new String (pg2_txtf_2);
this.g2_txtf_3 =new String (pg2_txtf_3);
this.g2_txtf_4 =new String (pg2_txtf_4);
this.txtf_autre =new String (ptxtf_autre);
this.g6_txf1 =new String (pg6_txf1);
this.g6_txf2 =new String (pg6_txf2);
this.g6_txf3=new String (pg6_txf3);

};

    public String getADSN() {
        return ADSN;
    }
...(other get methods)
```

Comment: Where are all those `TextField`s in `LayoutController` created/ added to the scene? You need to provide a [mcve]. BTW: `String`s are immutable. In at least 99.99% of all cases creating a copy of a string by passing a `String` to the constructor of `String` is just a waste of memory. just assign the constructor parameters to the fields directly: `this.ADSN = pADSN; ...`

Comment: @fabian , thank you for your remark , next time i will provide better examples ,and for the `TextField` yes they are all created and added to the scene